# English-language meta-search engine with good coverage of Korean airlines?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, south-korea, flight-search-engines, low-cost-carriers

When I search for flights from South Korea to nearby countries on Google Flights, there are usually many flights from airlines which don't share fare data with Google, for example: T'Way, Eastar Jet, Jin Air, Jeju Air, Korean Air (see picture).

[image]

For Google Flights, this is an unusually large amount of airlines with unavailable price data (on most searches, there are just one or two with unavailable prices). Is there a different English-language meta-search engine with good coverage of South Korean airlines' fares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [Kayak](https://www.kayak.com) and [Skyscanner](https://www.skyscanner.com) should provide you what you are looking for, don't they?

It not, then you might want to try the airlines' websites directly.

Comment: OP here; Skyscanner ended up featuring most of the airlines I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[Skyticket](http://skyticket.com) generally has better coverage of budget carriers in Japan. For instance they show prices for Spring Airlines Japan which neither Google Flights nor Skyscanner does.

This seems to be the case in South Korea to some extent. They seem to cover all the Korean budget airlines in flights *to* South Korea (from Japan and other countries) but on the example route in the direction Seoul to Tokyo they were missing the budget airlines. The prices Skyticket shows also seem to correspond to the airlines' sites in contrast to Kayak where the prices seem to be marked up.

[image: Skyticket]

Answer (score 1):

It might not have all of them but I have checked it has Eastar Jet and Korean Air:

[kiwi.com](https://kiwi.com)

P.S. Plus it can combine them (with transfers for a cheaper flight) whichever way it likes.